# Shape key and driver Problems Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, drivers, shape-keys

I'm rigging a character and I would like to fix spots that weight painting won't fix with shape keys.
But assigning bone as a driver doesn't do anything.
It's controlled by an IK bone and doesn't seem to have any rotation information of it's own.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include some pictures of the driver in question?

Comment: Can i upload the blend file?

Comment: @Skullfaceguy use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Unfortunately due to how constraints are implemented, you don't always have local space rotations available from them. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112657/how-to-drive-shape-keys-based-on-the-angle-between-two-bones?rq=1 has one way of getting around this

Comment: I tried this in 2,79 and they did have their own rotation values, so this might be a 2,8 issue